# using BootstrapVue with Vue.Draggable? and drop items from list to b-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, bootstrap-vue, vue.draggable

is it possible to use `Vue.Draggable` with `BootstrapVue` Table?

and second question: is it possible to drag items from a list to column in a B-table, so i get after dropping a column field with the name of the item from the list?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I did not succeed to do that with Draggable and B-table, so I would advise you to use the [scrollabelJs](https://github.com/SortableJS/sortablejs).
The solution is described in there : [sortable not dragging all columns of table in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936500/sortable-not-dragging-all-columns-of-table-in-safari)